# Need some idea for about scrollbar and side menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Need some idea for about scrollbar and side menu ?

```
<body style=" margin: 0px; ">
    <div style="position: absolute; width: 200px; height: 2000px; background: red;"></div>
    <div style="width: 100%;height: 3000px;background: blue;"></div>
</body>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ergjbvz5/

Element div red is side menu and element div blue main web site area.

When user scroll page until end of Element div red and user still scroll page. How can i do for fixed Element div red and scroll only Element div blue ?

Comment: try `position:fixed` in red instead of `position:absolute`

Comment: Not work. But with is way user can not scroll page until end of element red.

Comment: Just add "overflow-x:auto" for x scroll

Answer (score 0):

**It may help you, try this:**

```html
<body style=" margin: 0px; ">
    <div style="position: fixed; width: 30%; height: 100%; background: red;">Test sidebar</div>
    <div style="margin-left:30%;height: 3000px;background: blue;">
      Test body
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Not work. But with is way user can not scroll page until end of element red.

Answer (score 0):

@Robert Down You just need to change "position" of red color div.

```html
<body style=" margin: 0px; ">
    <div style="position: fixed; width: 200px; height: 2000px; background: red;">grghrughrughr<br>
    grghrughrughr<br>grghrughrughr<br>grghrughrughr<br>grghrughrughr<br>
    rrghrig</div>
    <div style="width: 100%;height: 3000px;background: blue;"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Not work. But with is way user can not scroll page until end of element red.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```html
<body style=" margin: 0px; ">
    <div style="position: fixed; width: 200px; height: 100%; overflow:auto;">
      <div style="position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 2000px; background: red;"></div>
    </div>
  <div style="width: 100%;height: 3000px;background: blue;"></div>
</body>
```